# How to keep bootstrap 4 nav below heading in desktop, but above on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4 grid layout. The first row contains only heading. The second row contains vertical nav that I keep aligned with the content by placing it in the same row. However, I want to keep the heading above the content and the nav, in Desktop only. I want the nav to be top left corner when in mobile. Below is the solution I used by duplicating my Heading. Is there a better way to achieve the same effect?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row hidden-sm-down">
    <div class="col">
      <h1 class="text-center">Desktop Header</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <!--Nav Bar-->
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 push-md-8">
      <div class="bootstrap-vertical-nav">
        <button class="btn btn-primary hidden-md-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseElement" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseElement">
              <span class="fa fa-navicon"></span>
            </button>
        <div class="collapse fill-gutter" id="collapseElement">
          <ul class="nav flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--End Nav Bar-->
    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-9 pull-md-3">
      <h1 class="text-center hidden-md-up">Mobile header</h1>
      <div class="row" id="page_body">
        <h2>Content Goes Here</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to check whether browser is from mobile or pc.

```
var filter = "win16|win32|win64|mac|macintel";
var deviceType = "";

if (navigator.platform ) {
    console.log(navigator.platform);
    if (filter.indexOf(navigator.platform.toLowerCase()) < 0) {
        deviceType = "MOBILE";
    } else {
        deviceType = "PC";
    }
    console.log(deviceType);
}
```

then make separate css code what you want to show in each devices.

But if you don't want to use this, you have to use `media Query`

Comment: I'm using responsive bootstrap 4 classes `hidden-sm-down` and `hidden-md-up`. They work fine, but I am concerned with the fact that I have two headings in my html (one for small screen, one for medium and up).

Comment: @Yason oh I misunderstood your purpose.. well, then I'm sorry to I can't help this. T.T